# How does "time segmented volume" differ from on-balance volume?

Tags: technicals, indicator

Worden Brothers Inc. advertise a proprietary indicator called [**Time Segmented Volume**](http://www.worden.com/legacy/TeleChartHelp/Content/Indicators/Time_Segmented_Volume.htm).

This gizmo *seems* closely to resemble [**On Balance Volume**](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/o/onbalancevolume.asp#axzz1jpgGAbP5).

Is there any reason to think that TSV might yield a more useful or timely signal than OBV?

Comment: @Tal Fishman -- thanks for the edit, much better now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this is the key difference between OBV and TSV:

"Time segmented volume is the way to get consistent volume data and eliminate all the volume distortions that we discussed above. Here's the key to why time segmented volume works: Let's start with volume on a 5 minute chart and for this example, look at the 10:15 bar. Now take the average of only the 10:15 bars over the prior month and compare that average to the current 10:15 bar. The difference will give a true reading on whether today's 10:15 bar volume is higher or lower in comparison to the exact same time bars over the past month."

from: http://www.squidoo.com/Time_Segmented_Volume

OBV is based on a cumulative total volume, while TSV compares the current time period to a previous one, no running total.

As to which is "better", well that depends on a lot of things and it would be unrealistic to assume that one was better than the other in all cases.